# Filtered list in URL for hierarchical data with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Viewsets in Django Rest Framework keep my code very clean: I can define a model and then a viewset to go along with it.

However, how do I best deal with models which are hierarchically under another one? For example: I have a `Project` which has many `File`s and want this API:

1. `GET   /api/files`: get all files across all projects
2. `GET   /api/files/:id`: detail a particular file
3. `GET   /api/projects/:id/files`: list all files in a project

The following code *almost* works, except that the URL for 3. comes out as `api/files/projects/:id`:

```py
class FileViewSet(
    mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    queryset = File.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FileSerializer

    @action(methods=["get"], url_path="projects/(?P<project_id>[^/.]+)", detail=False)
    def list_for_project(self, request, project_id):
        project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
        # ... list only Files for this Project
```

I have looked in to a few solutions such as writing custom routers, using more than one viewset or view, or custom packages; but I'm surprised that it isn't easy to do with DRF out-of-the-box within one `Viewset`. Am I missing a trick? What do people usually do in this scenario?

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this: https://blog.apptension.com/2017/09/13/rest-api-using-django-rest-framework/ which talks about how to build a nested API

Answer (score 0):

For this, you should create relation between 2 different models. In the **file** model create 1 field with a foreign key association to projects.

```
class File(models.Model):
    projects = models.ForeignKey(Projects)
```

Comment: That gives me the needed relation for the Django models, but it doesn't automatically create the REST API that I want.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is you need to simplify the code at the same time you need to do all these three. 
Usage of `mixins` is a great way to implement api, but in my opinion I recommend you to use `ModelViewSet`, for more details [click here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset)
Its the simplest way in which you don't need to specify the url patterns like `projects/(?P<project_id>[^/.]+)`, 
I will give you an example code

> views.py

```
from rest_framework import view sets
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import ModelName
from .serializers import SerializerName

class TestAPIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ModelName.objects.all()
    serialiser_class = SerializerName
```

> urls.py

```
import rest_framework import routers
from .views import TestAPIView


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('test',TestAPIView, base_name="api-test")
urlpatterns= router.urls
```

The first two will work correctly with this way
and for the third one, you can deal it with `creating multiple model classes projects and files` add foreign key relation between these classes
example:

```
class ProjectModel(models.Model):
   ...
   ...

class FileModel(models.Model):
   project = models.ForeignKey(ProjectModel);
   ....
   ....
```